# Как получить ид чата из @bot.callback_query_handler (библеотека:PyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telebot

Вот код

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Выбрать серию", callback_data='Выбор серии')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("❓ Задать вопрос", callback_data='Вопросы')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     text='Привет', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def start_callback(call):
    if call.data == 'Выбор серии':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        gm = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Вернуться в главное меню', callback_data='Главное меню')
        markup.add(gm)
        bot.edit_message_text(
            'Ниже с помощью кнопок ты можешь выбрать серию!,
            call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)

    elif call.data == 'Главное меню':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Выбрать серию", callback_data='Выбор серии')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("❓ Задать вопрос", callback_data='Вопросы')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.edit_message_text(call.message.chat.id,
                              'Привет'
                              .format(call.message.from_user), call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=markup)
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Ну и когда нажимаю кнопку вернутся в главное меню выдает ошибку: Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found

Помогите правильно написать call чтобы правильно указать ид чата
в call.data == 'Главное меню'

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+id+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

Из-за невнимательности не увидел 2 раза написанное call.message.chat.id в

```
        bot.edit_message_text(**call.message.chat.id**,
                              'Привет'
                              .format(call.message.from_user), **call.message.chat.id**, call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=markup)
```

правильный вариант должен был выглядеть так

```
        bot.edit_message_text(call.message.chat.id
                              'Привет'
                              .format(call.message.from_user), call.message.chat.id,
                              reply_markup=markup)
```